# TreeViewItem and null value

Tags: c#, wpf

Not sure it is me after a long day of work ... or something is different in WPF type trees. I'm adding data to a tree and then when it is a parent node need to add its children but SelectedItem is always null!

any comment or direction would be helpful.

Thanks.

XAML:

```
  <TreeView x:Name="TreeView1" Grid.Row="0">
  </TreeView>

Code:
       TreeView myTree = FindChild<TreeView>(Application.Current.MainWindow, "TreeView1");

       myTree.Items.Add(ObjEmployee.Tag);
       TreeViewItem tvi = (TreeViewItem) myTree.SelectedItem;  
//my assumption was that when an item is added to tree most recent used node will be selected but it seems something is avoiding it or maybe works in a different way.
```

Comment: Default behaviour of TreeView is NOT to select when we add item.

Comment: exactly .. I updated my answer .. you can manually select.

Answer (score 0):

You should post some code snippet .. I do not understand what you need.

If you are using Hierarchical Template ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx )
The object of the SelectIedtem will be one of the data you put in ItemsSource

---

Otherwise, the "SelectedItem" can be any type of visual component that you put inside the treeview.

```
var treeItem = myTree.SelectedItem;
if (treeItem != null)
    treeitem.GetType().Name;
```

Normally using TreeViewItem inside the treeview, all objects are in treeViewItem.Items

---

(Edit) You can try this:

```
            var result = FindVisualChildren<TreeViewItem>(treeView);

            foreach (var item in result)
            {
                if (item.IsSelected)
                {
                    ....
                }
            }
```

and

```
    public static IEnumerable<T> FindVisualChildren<T>(FrameworkElement depObj) where T : FrameworkElement
    {
        if (depObj != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj); i++)
            {
                FrameworkElement child = (FrameworkElement)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i);
                if (child != null && child is T)
                {
                    yield return (T)child;
                }

                foreach (T childOfChild in FindVisualChildren<T>(child))
                {
                    yield return childOfChild;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have updated my question by adding the piece I'm having problem. Also, tried this code posted by you but did not help.Thank you

Comment: But foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'System.Windows.Controls.TreeViewItem'

Comment: sorry, I forgot the "var result = ..."

Comment: Thanks but I'm wondering why things should be that complicated in WPF. Now, I'm getting an error as:  foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'System.Windows.Controls.TreeViewItem' because 'System.Windows.Controls.TreeViewItem' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

Comment: Well, you can apply a foreach on a IEnumerator (List,Array,Etc)
The method I posted, returns a collection of visual components, in the example: TreeViewItem

Comment: if you want to traverse a collection, search by property "Items" .. (treeViewItem.Items)

Comment: No, all I want to do is to add children to a node (if it has 1 or more children). I'm using HeadedItemsControl so when I add this object to tree so wondering if this is causing the issue. any idea?